# getting error when converting html to image using html2image

Tags: python, html, css, django, image

I am trying to convert html to png image using html2image python module, version 2.0.3(latest)
This is the code I am executing in python shell, but I am getting this error.
Please help!!

```
>>> from html2image import Html2Image
>>> hti = Html2Image(temp_path="/tmp", output_path="/var/www/html/commonservice/htmltoimage",  custom_flags=["--no-sandbox", "--headless", "--hide-scrollbars", "--disable-gpu", "--default-background-color=ffffff"])
>>> html = """<h1> An interesting title </h1> This page will be red"""
>>> css = "body {background: red;}"
>>> hti.screenshot(html_str=html, css_str=css, save_as='temp_image.png')
/snap/chromium/2406/snap/command-chain/desktop-launch: line 369: cannot create temp file for here-document: No such file or directory
[0403/090244.518985:WARNING:bluez_dbus_manager.cc(247)] Floss manager not present, cannot set Floss enable/disable.
[0403/090244.553724:WARNING:sandbox_linux.cc(393)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
[0403/090244.788897:ERROR:headless_command_handler.cc(222)] Failed to write file /var/www/html/commonservice/htmltoimage/temp_image.png: No such file or directory (2)
['/var/www/html/commonservice/htmltoimage/temp_image.png']
```

Comment: Does the `/tmp` forlder exist and can the current user write into this folder? Same for the output folder? Try writing to these folders without *html2image* and just with plain Python code.

Comment: @PatrickJanser yes the folder `/tmp` exist and also the current user root has writing permission for this folder

Comment: Potentially related issue + workaround: https://github.com/vgalin/html2image/issues/46